# Insert into table where id is not null and auto increment sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to add some values into a table, but I get an error for not manually inputting the id.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE history (
   ...>     id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   ...>     user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
   ...>     shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
   ...>     type TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     PRIMARY KEY(id),
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT INTO history (user_id,symbol,price,shares,timestamp,type) VALUES (1,'NFLX',202.83,2,'2022/06/09 02:14:25','buy');
Runtime error: NOT NULL constraint failed: history.id (19)
```

When I remove 'not null' the id just stays null

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE history (
   ...>     id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
   ...>     user_id INTEGER,
   ...>     symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
   ...>     shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
   ...>     timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
   ...>     type TEXT NOT NULL,
   ...>     PRIMARY KEY(id),
   ...>     FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
   ...> );
sqlite> INSERT INTO history (user_id,symbol,price,shares,timestamp,type) VALUES (1,'NFLX',202.83,2,'2022/06/09 02:14:25','buy');
sqlite> SELECT * FROM history;
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+------+
| id | user_id | symbol | price  | shares |      timestamp      | type |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+------+
|    | 1       | NFLX   | 202.83 | 2      | 2022/06/09 02:14:25 | buy  |
+----+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: And then give https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html a thorough read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer Shawn gave worked, which is to remove AUTO_INCREMENT
https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

```
CREATE TABLE history (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    symbol TEXT NOT NULL,
    price NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
    timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL,
    type TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set(insert) a value for the primary AUTOINCREMENT column, it is also not recommended to use "AUTOINCREMENT", the right syntax that will do exactly what you want is :

```
id "INTEGER" PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

As you start to insert the values (without inserting the ID value), it automatically will check the last ID value and then increment it to be the ID for the row, note that the first column will be set automatically to 1 by default.

Comment: Yes you can insert a value for the primary autoincrement column. But the keyword is `AUTOINCREMENT` and not `AUTO_INCREMENT`